# Missing required metadata WP 8 app submission

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-7

I have this error displayed when trying to submit my app:

[image: error list]

This error applies to all the languages I intend to support for my app apart from the default language(English) which was not listed among the error list.

I have added all necessary metadata which I think only applies for the default language(English).

How do I make these metadata available for other languages my app support. In my .csproj file I  this:

```
<SupportedCultures>fr%3bar%3bzh-Hans%3bzh-Hant%3bhi%3bpt%3bru%3bes%3btr</SupportedCultures>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the DevCenter, you have to type the description and upload the screenshots for every language individually. Just change the current language on the list, then upload your assets. It is a step of the submission process, it has nothing to do with the application itself.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the *default language* in the AppManifest:Packaging section is identical to the selected language in the *Supported Languages* section if you only intend on supporting one language in your application submission.